# Running Python async server loop and Future concurrently

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, pywin32, python-sockets

I am working on a project where I have a simple socket server looking for connections to reply to the client with a message in a message queue. At the same time, I have a monitoring system using PyWin32 that is looking for changes to files in a directory. When PyWin32 detects a file change, it should append the info to a message queue. When the server detects a connection, it should fetch the relevant information from the message queue. The server will be constantly looking for connections, while PyWin32 only runs when a change is detected.

I can run them successfully separately, but not together. It seems like my code gets hung up on one function and the other stops processing. I've read the documentation and perused SO posts, but nothing seems to solve my issue.

Here's a sample of the Socket Server:

```
class TestSocketServer:
    def __init__(self,
                 # response_handler: Callable
                 ):
        self._alive: bool = False

        # Configure client-server connection
        self._host: str = 'localhost'
        self._port: int = 50000

        self._mq = {}

    def _respond(self, reader):
        request = self._mq[reader].get()

        return f"Got request {request}"

    async def _client_connected(self, reader, writer):
        data = await reader.read(1024)

        # print(reader, type(reader))
        message = data.decode()
        print(message)

        self._mq[reader]: queue.Queue = queue.Queue()
        self._mq[reader].put_nowait(message)

        response = self._respond(reader)

        writer.write(response.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        writer.close()

    async def handle_traffic(self):
        server = await asyncio.start_server(
            self._client_connected,
            self._host,
            self._port)

        await server.serve_forever()

    def start(self):
        asyncio.run(self.handle_traffic())
```

The PyWin32 handler looks like this:

```
    async def _monitor(self):
        """
        Look for changes in directory and return them
        :return: FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION
        """
        ReadDirectoryChangesW(self._handle,  # Python version of Windows Handle
                          self._buffer,
                          TRUE,  # Monitor directory tree
                          # Attributes to monitor
                          (FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                           FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                           FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                           FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                           FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE)
                          )

        change = FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION(self._buffer, 9999)

        action, item = change[0]
        act_str = EventWatcher._ACTIONS.get(action)

        if change:
            chg_msg = {str(time.time()): [str(act_str), item]}
            # TODO try to push changes through socket before persisting
            await self._write_changes(action=action, change=chg_msg)
    async.run(self._monitor)
```

How I've tried implementing them (which excludes the async.run() calls):

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(self.handle_traffic())
loop.create_task(self.monitor())
loop.run_forever()
```

I've also tried creating a Future in my loop for the monitoring portion:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(self.handle_traffic())
fut = loop.create_future()
loop.create_task(self.monitor(fut))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you implemented them together. From what you're showing, I guess you are using 'asyncio.run()' wrong. This is supposed to be your entry point for your whole async program, so don't use it in a method.

Comment: Gotcha. I've tired a few implementations with no luck, but let me include what I've tried.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword added. When using event loops I encounter the same issue, where one coroutine seems to block the other.

Comment: Coroutines block the whole event loop if they contain blocking code. I'm not familiar with a lot of the pywin32 API, but it's definitely not async compatible. Chances are you need to find the blocking bits in your code and run them in a thread or find an async framework to monitor your fs.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword I was starting to suspect I would need threads but wanted to avoid them if possible.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword I'm fairly certain it's the PyWin32 function that is blocking. It basically just sits in that function until it detects a change.

Comment: Understandable, but it's not possible withouts threads. If you absolutely don't want to, you could also just make a sort of microservice and communicate the fs events through a socket.

Comment: That would definitely work, although that's basically what I'm already doing and I'd like to avoid adding another layer if possible. Threading should work fine for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @thisisalsomypassword for pointing out that my Win32 API calls were blocking the rest of my script, and that I would need to utilize threads. Doing this below implementation fixed my problem:

```
class TestSocketServer:
    def __init__(self,
                 # response_handler: Callable
                 ):
        self._alive: bool = False

        # Configure client-server connection
        self._host: str = 'localhost'
        self._port: int = 50000

        self._mq = {}

    def _respond(self, reader):
        request = self._mq[reader].get()

        return f"Got request {request}"

    async def _client_connected(self, reader, writer):
        data = await reader.read(1024)

        # print(reader, type(reader))
       message = data.decode()
        print(message)

        self._mq[reader]: queue.Queue = queue.Queue()
        self._mq[reader].put_nowait(message)

        response = self._respond(reader)

        writer.write(response.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        writer.close()

    async def start_serving(self):
        await asyncio.start_server(
            self._client_connected,
            self._host,
            self._port)
```

For the watcher:

```
    def monitor(self):
        """
        Look for changes in directory and return them
        :return: FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION
        """
        while True:
            ReadDirectoryChangesW(self._handle,  # Python version of Windows Handle
                                  self._buffer,
                                  TRUE,  # Monitor directory tree
                                  # Attributes to monitor
                                  (FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                                   FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE)
                                )

            change = FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION(self._buffer, 9999)

            action, item = change[0]
            print(change)
```

Then implementing the two this way works:

```
self._server = TestSocketServer()
self._watcher = EventWatcher()

def main(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(self._watcher.monitor))
    loop.create_task(self._server.start_serving())
    loop.run_forever()

main()
```

Now, whenever there is either a socket request or a change in the filesystem, I see both appear, and the program continues as expected to handle future inputs.

Comment: `asyncio.to_thread()` was new to me. So thanks for that!

Comment: My pleasure! I work primarily as a data scientist, so all of this was WAY outside my wheelhouse XD   thanks again for the help!